# How to draw opposite inverse triangle?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm playing around with some code today (I'm a beginner). I just wrote a simple program to make a triangle in which the base is determined by the user's input.

Here is the code:

```
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int triBase = 0;

    cout << "Enter a base number for the triangle [1-100]: ";
    cin >> triBase;
    cout << endl;
    while(!cin || triBase > 100 || triBase <= 0)
    {   
        system ("clear");
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10, '\n');
        cout << "Enter a base number for the triangle [1-100]: ";
        cin >> triBase;
        cout << endl;
    }   

    system ("clear");
    for(int lines = 0; lines < triBase; lines++)
    {   
        for(int rows = 0; rows <= lines; rows++)
        {   
            cout << "* ";
        }   
    cout << endl;
    }   


    return 0;   
}
```

My question is, how would I go about making the triangle appear on the opposite side of the screen in an inverse order? Example, the user enters 5, the screen would show:

```
*                                                            *****
**                                                            ****
***                                                            ***
****                                                            **
*****                                                            *
```

Or if they enter 12:

```
*                                                       ************
**                                                       ***********
***                                                       **********
****                                                       *********
*****                                                       ********
******                                                       *******
*******                                                       ******
********                                                       *****
*********                                                       ****
**********                                                       ***
***********                                                       **                
************                                                       *
```

Is there a way to know how may characters can fit across the screen, subtract the number of characters that would fit on that line, then add the difference in spaces in order for them to start in the correct place so that each line ends at the last spot on the screen? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Add a const number of spaces on every row iteration (new line). As you see, spaces are constantly repetitive.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
   for (int lines = 0; lines < triBase; lines++)
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows <= lines; rows++)
        {
            cout << "* ";
        }

        cout << std::string(30, ' '); // 30 spaces

        for(int i = 0; i < triBase - lines; i++)
        {
            cout << "* ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
```

As you see, on every line, and once you are done with plotting your `*`, then I add a const number of spaces and execute a new for loop to display the `*` as `triBase - lines` times.

Also, it is better to think about it as a 2D table with rows and columns, so your `lines` are actually rows, and your `rows` are actually columns.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work. Here is the final code:

```
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int triBase = 0;
    string spaces(30, ' '); 

    cout << "Enter a base number for the triangle [1-100]: ";
    cin >> triBase;
    cout << endl;
    while(!cin || triBase > 100 || triBase <= 0)
    {   
        system ("clear");
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10, '\n');
        cout << "Enter a base number for the triangle [1-100]: ";
        cin >> triBase;
        cout << endl;
    }   

    system ("clear");
    for(int lines = 0; lines < triBase; lines++)
    {   
        for(int rows = 0; rows <= lines; rows++)
        {   
            cout << "* ";
        }   
        cout << spaces;
        for(int secondRow = 0; secondRow < triBase - lines; secondRow++)
        {   
            cout << "* ";
        }   
        cout << endl;
    }   

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: No reason for using a for loop to display a const number of spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix that.

Comment: See what @NathanOliver suggested in the comments

Comment: @FirstStep got it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you! That was much easier.

Comment: @FirstStep much appreciated.